# why is mailgraph not updating?

Tags: monitoring, postfix, ubuntu-10.04

I just installed mailgraph on a Linux Ubuntu 10.04 box monitoring Postifix.
Everything seems to be working fine, but the graphs are not always
updating.  When I refresh the web page or close the browser and come back
later, the graph updates and moves to the left, showing new time, the the
data line is not drawn.  Sometimes it does not update for several hours.  I
had started, stopped and restarted mailgraph-init and that doesn't seem to
make a difference.

Any ideas?

Comment: This will sound like a silly question, but do you have mail going through the server at all?  I thought I had a problem with mailgraph not updating a while back and it turned out that I had a misconfiguration to where the server was not accepting any mail.  So there was nothing to graph.

Comment: yes, I have some email on my mail server. I have sent to other domain, and receive from other domain. But, the graph not update.

Comment: Yes, I have do all instruction tutorial on internet. But, why mailgraph is not updating? can you tell me what the parameter use by mailgraphh on /usr/sbin/mailgraph.pl to update rrd file within 5 minutes ? thanks for your help.
n_n

Answer (score 1):

This might help- I figured out that perl modules called by the script where missing, and tracked it back to missing dependencies. I did a clean install on Ubuntu Lucid install using the following and it worked immediately:

apt-get -y install rrdtool mailgraph librrds-perl libfile-tail-perl

These dependencies (librrds-perl libfile-tail-perl) are listed on the lucid package details, but "apt-get install mailgraph" only installs rrdtool automatically for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a time and date problem. If you change the date and time for more than a few minutes then mailgraph stops further records.

Can you delete the files under /var/lib/mailgraph/ and then restart mailgraph? It takes some time until mailgraph has rebuilt its database from the logfile.

Please note that the graph is only updated every 5 minutes. So you can't see the current counts.

Are you sure that Postfix logs all mails to "/var/log/mail.log" and mailgraph uses this file (defined in /etc/default/mailgraph)?

Comment: thanks for the reply. Yes, I make sure postfix log to /var/log/mail.log and mailgraph uses it.
does mailgraph update every 5 minutes? so, what the function parameter $rrdstep=60 in /usr/sbin/mailgraph.pl ? I think mailgraph update every 1 minutes. Even I'm wait for 10 minutes, mailgraph is not updating. And the result is different with pflogsumm.

Comment: If you didn't change (DON'T DO IT) /usr/sbin/mailgraph.pl then it is 5 minutes. Have you done all I said in §2?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem!

**The problem is:**

Implementation of mailgraph.pl of package are wrong in the date...

I recomended to you make try an other download from other source.

DONT USE APT-GET or PORTS for this pkg!

Comment: If there is a problem with the package, it should be fixed within the distribution, not by directing people elsewhere. Please report it.